# Composer not showing updated php version

Tags: php, neo4j, composer-php

I am trying to get composer to install a script for me.
However the requirement of the script is min php 5.6, i uodated my php version
to php 7, and composer still kept showing me the old version so i reinstalled it and manually pointed it to the latest php.exe.
It till shows the same error.

```
 Problem 1
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha7 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha6 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha5 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha4 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha3 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha2 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0-alpha1 requires php >= 5.6 -> your PHP v
ersion (5.5.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for graphaware/neo4j-php-client ^4.0@alpha -> satisfi
able by graphaware/neo4j-php-client[4.0.0-alpha1, 4.0.0-alpha2, 4.0.0-alpha3, 4.
0.0-alpha4, 4.0.0-alpha5, 4.0.0-alpha6, 4.0.0-alpha7].
```

Comment: What's the actual command that you run? Is the correct `composer.bat` being called? Try `where composer` in a Windows command line to find out what is being run.

Comment: I am using the composer.json file provided by neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the old composer was still existing, I right clicked on the compose.json file and ran the new composer and everything worked.
Thank You Marcel.